# How can I use only one section for my home page

Tags: css, css-position

[image: Site picture]

I want to use my home page on the white section of the screen as I indicated in my picture.

However, the title has been shown on the left-top corner of the screen as you see.

How can I handle this?

I just want to use half of the screen as a content. The header picture and navbar should stay fixed

```css
header .img-area {
  position: fixed
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #021e34;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 25em;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<header>
  <div class="img-area">
    <img src="./Images/photo1.jpg" alt="photo1" />
  </div>
</header>

<!-- Navbar -->

<nav>
  <a href="#" class="logo">LOGO</a>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Curriculum Vitae</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">References</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="icons">
    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
    <i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i>
  </div>

  <small>©2021 Cihan Özcan</small>
</nav>

<!-- Main -->

<main>
  <!-- Home Section -->
  <section id="home-sec">
    <h2>Title</h2>
  </section>
</main>
```

How can I set the main section?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  Maybe a picture of desired outcome would be helpful?

Comment: I just want to use half of the screen as a content. The header picture and navbar should stay fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<nav>` and your `<header>` are both `position: fixed` - which means they are **outside the flow** of the document.

Consequently, you need to clearly indicate how far to the right of the left-side of the document your `<main>` element is, since without this information, the browser assumes that the *top-left corner* of the first **in-flow element** (in this case `<main>`) is the *top-left corner* of the browser viewport.

To communicate to the browser that your `<main>` element starts some way to the right, you need to give it a `margin-left`.

To do this, you'll need to:

- give your `<header>` an explicit width - let's say `400px`
- give your `<main>` a `margin-left` of `900px` (ie. `400px` + `500px`)

---

**Example:**

```
header {
width: 400px;
}

main {
  margin-left: 900px;
}
```

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction#positioning_techniques

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood that one fixed thing is enough and it solved my problem.